# How can I combined Baffle.js with an Angularjs app

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a div that I would like to scramble with [baffle.js](https://camwiegert.github.io/baffle/#demo), it is supposed to be a pure javascript text animation library and I would like to be able to replace the scrambled text with a server update (SSE) before it gets revealed.

I can handle the server stuff I just need to know how I can combine a non-angular js library like baffle into my angular controller.

**Html**:

`<div class="baffle">ad124asfd$afarA1</div>`

When server responds I'd like to overwrite the div with my actual data:

`<div class="baffle">{{Server Response}}</div>`

Then finally stop the scramble animation so the new data is visible in the dom:

`<div class="baffle">My server response!</div>`

**Here's my controller**:

```
app.controller("MainController", ['$scope', 'LxNotificationService', '$http', 'postService', 'getService', '$baffle', function ($scope, LxNotificationService, $http, postService, getService, $baffle) {

// Start baffle on any element(s).
$scope.scramble = function () {
    $('.baffle').each(function(i) {
      (function() {
        var Baffle;
        Baffle = function() {
          function Baffle() {
            var $baffle, b;
            $baffle = $('.baffle');
            b = baffle('.baffle', {
              characters: '+-\u2022~\u2591\u2588\u2593 \u2593\u2592\u2591!=*',
              speed: 100
            });
            $baffle.addClass('is-started');
            b.start();
            b.reveal(2000);
            setTimeout(()=>inProgress = false,2500)
          }
          return Baffle;
        }();
        $(function() {
          return new Baffle();
        });
      }.call(this));
    });
};

$scope.scramble();


}]);
```

All I get are injector errors in the controller, but if I don't inject it as a dependency it says baffle undefined... `$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $baffleProvider <- $baffle <- MainController`

Comment: You can read up on adding external libraries here https://www.jvandemo.com/how-to-properly-integrate-non-angularjs-libraries-in-your-angularjs-application/

Comment: @Oluwaseye, thanks I got further with this but it's not clear to me if his code is suppose to go into the controller or somewhere else. I wish he had made a codepen or something, do you think you could show me?

Right now I get an error on this line as it's not defined: `ngModule.factory('baffle', baffleFactory);`

Comment: Did you create a factory, service of bafflejs lib ?  When you do create a module of the library, within you can add a factory or service of the module that you'll use in your controller. Check out this link http://jameshill.io/articles/angular-third-party-injection-pattern/

Comment: @Oluwaseye I read it over 5 times, but it's a little over my head. I gave it my best shot here and I think I'm pretty close but would really appreciate if you could help:

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qXjpJG?editors=1010

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Here's what i came up with as an easy solve based on what you have.
>
> You can have your Angularjs code do whatever it's suppose to do and
>   then you around with the logic of timing.
>
> Since **AngularJS** looses the value of **{{text}}** when it is set directly.
>
> I decided to have **2** divs.
>
> The div with the class "**baffle**" plays with baffle but hides after **3
>   seconds** using the ng-hide directive that sets to true and hides the
>   div.
>
> The div of class **angulartextDiv** gets its value from the **text** variable.

See the code below.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <div class="angulartextDiv">
      {{ text }} 
    </div>
    <div ng-hide="hideDiv" class="baffle"> 
      Testing my text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/camwiegert/baffle/master/dist/baffle.min.js"></script>
<script>
   var c = baffle('.baffle')
    .start()
    .set({
        characters: "+-\u2022~\u2591\u2588\u2593 \u2593\u2592\u2591!=*",
        speed: 100
    });
  c.start();
  c.reveal(3000);
</script>
```

**AngularJS**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {
 // Your code    
  $scope.mytext = function() {
        $scope.text = "Testing my text"; 
    };
   $timeout( function(){
           return $scope.mytext();
        }, 3000 );

   $timeout(function() {
         $scope.hideDiv = true;
      }, 3000);
});
```

Here's the codepen https://codepen.io/seyz4all/pen/VzWBqG

Hope this helps